# How to handle touchID when loading app from background Swift

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

I'm implementing the login possibility with touchID using Swift.
Following: when the App is started, there is a login screen and a touchID popup - that's working fine. The problem occurs, when the app is loaded from background: I want the touchID popup appear **over a login screen** if a specific timespan hasn't been exceeded yet - but this time I want the touchID to go to the last shown view before the app entered background. (i.e. if the user wants to cancel the touchID, there is a login screen underneath where he then can authenticate via password, which leads him to the last shown view **OR** if the touchID authentication succeeded, the login screen should be dismissed and the last shown view presented.)
I really tried everything on my own, and searched for answers - nothing did help me. Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //notify when foreground or background have been entered -> in that case there are two methods that will be invoked: willEnterForeground and didEnterBackground
    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "willEnterForeground", name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "didEnterBackground", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    password.secureTextEntry = true
    if (username != nil) {
        username.text = "bucketFit"
    }
    username.delegate = self
    password.delegate = self

    if let alreadyShown : AnyObject? = def.objectForKey("alreadyShown") {
        if (alreadyShown == nil){
            authenticateWithTouchID()
        }
    }
}
```

**willEnterForeground:**

```
func willEnterForeground() {
    //save locally that the guide already logged in once and the application is just entering foreground
    //the variable alreadyShown is used for presenting the touchID, see viewDidAppear method
    def.setObject(true, forKey: "alreadyShown")
    if let backgroundEntered : AnyObject? = def.objectForKey("backgroundEntered") {
        let startTime = backgroundEntered as! NSDate
        //number of seconds the app was in the background
        let inactivityDuration = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)
        //if the app was longer than 3 minutes inactiv, ask the guide to input his password
        if (inactivityDuration > 2) {
            showLoginView()
        } else {
            def.removeObjectForKey("alreadyShown")
            showLoginView()
        }
    }
}
```

**authenticateWithTouchID():**

```
func authenticateWithTouchID() {
    let context : LAContext = LAContext()
    context.localizedFallbackTitle = ""
    var error : NSError?
    let myLocalizedReasonString : NSString = "Authentication is required"
    //check whether the iphone has the touchID possibility at all
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        //if yes then execute the touchID and see whether the finger print matches
        context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: myLocalizedReasonString as String, reply: { (success : Bool, evaluationError : NSError?) -> Void in
            //touchID succeded -> go to students list page
            if success {
                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("studentsList", sender: self)
                })
            } else {
                // Authentification failed
                print(evaluationError?.description)
                //print out the specific error
                switch evaluationError!.code {
                case LAError.SystemCancel.rawValue:
                    print("Authentication cancelled by the system")
                case LAError.UserCancel.rawValue:
                    print("Authentication cancelled by the user")
                default:
                    print("Authentication failed")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:**

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if (false) { //TODO -> username.text!.isEmpty || password.text!.isEmpty
        notify("Login failed", message: "Please enter your username and password to proceed")
        return false
    } else if (false) { //TODO when backend ready! -> !login("bucketFit", password: "test")
        notify("Incorrect username or password", message: "Please try again")
        return false
        //if the login page is loaded after background, dont proceed (then we need to present the last presented view on the stack before the app leaved to background)
    } else if let alreadyShown : AnyObject? = def.objectForKey("alreadyShown") {
        if (alreadyShown != nil){
            //TODO check whether login data is correct
            dismissLoginView()
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

**Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is create a AuthenticationManager. This manager would be a shared instance which keep track of whether authentication needs to be renewed. You may also want this to contain all of the auth methods.

```
class AuthenticationManager {
  static let sharedInstance = AuthenticationManager()
  var needsAuthentication = false
}
```

In AppDelegate:

```
func willEnterForeground() {
    def.setObject(true, forKey: "alreadyShown")
    if let backgroundEntered : AnyObject? = def.objectForKey("backgroundEntered") {
        let startTime = backgroundEntered as! NSDate
        //number of seconds the app was in the background
        let inactivityDuration = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)
        //if the app was longer than 3 minutes inactiv, ask the guide to input his password
        if (inactivityDuration > 2) {
            AuthenticationManager.sharedInstance.needsAuthentication = true
        }
    }
}
```

Then, subclass UIViewController with a view controller named SecureViewController. Override viewDidLoad() in this subclass

```
override fun viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  if (AuthenticationManager.sharedInstance().needsAuthentication) {
    // call authentication methods
  }
}
```

Now, make all your View Controllers that require authentication subclasses of SecureViewController.